# Concatenating dataframes by index/columns elements

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.random(36).reshape((9,4)), index = np.arange(1, np.random.random(36).reshape((9,4)).shape[0]+1), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

te = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=1000), columns=['Number_test'])
```

I want to concatenate two dataframes by index of df to each corresponding element in column Number_test

Comment: Have you tried `pd.merge(df, te, left_index=True, right_on='Number_test')`? or `pd.merge(df.reset_index(), te, left_on='index', right_on='Number_test')`?

Comment: I'm not sure about first one, does it work?

Comment: The first one works. The second seems a bit off. Maybe because of the reset_index. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(df, te, left_index=True, right_on='Number_test')
```

or

```
pd.merge(df.reset_index(), te, left_on='index', right_on='Number_test')
```