# Python: Inserting DataFrames into larger DataFrame at given index value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, insert

I'm certain this is a trivial question but I cannot seem to find a solution. I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5
```

I also have some additional DataFrames (`df_a`, `df_b`) that I wish to insert into the the primary DataFrame (`df`). The additional DataFrames are saved to a dictionary with the key being the index of the row that I wish to insert the additional DataFrames after.

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', 'Y'],
                    'B': ['X', 'Y'],
                    'C': ['X', 'Y']})

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', 'Y'],
                    'B': ['X', 'Y'],
                    'C': ['X', 'Y']})

idx_dict = {}
idx_dict[1] = df_a
idx_dict[3] = df_b
```

The final result would resemble this:

```
>>> result
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
0  X  X  X
1  Y  Y  Y
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
0  X  X  X
1  Y  Y  Y
4  5  5  5
```

I've read through the python [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) docs but can't seem to find out how to specify the particular location I wish to insert the DataFrame. Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424932/concatenating-dataframes-by-index-columns-elements) but as my DataFrame indexes don't match this solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least what you want can be achieved by slicing and concatenating:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
idx_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(idx_dict.items()))
dfs = []
start_idx = 0
for idx in idx_dict:
    dfs.append(df.iloc[start_idx:idx + 1])
    dfs.append(idx_dict[idx])
    start_idx = idx + 1
dfs.append(df.iloc[start_idx:])
result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

I think "inserting" `df_a` and `df_b` is difficult because the pandas data is actually a numpy array, which cannot be resized.

Comment: Thanks akai. I'm surprised there's no function that does this but that's a great solution. Cheers.